# objective c Project setup on xcode missing frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I am trying to setup an Objective-C project in xCode. The project was copied and sent in a zip file. I am trying to build the code but it has errors and there are missing frameworks. I tried running the pod install and it successfully installed the dependencies. But in xcode it is still highlighted as red. How would I fix this problem ? thanks

[image]

I've run the pod install and successfully installed the dependencies. please see attached image below.

[image]

and this is what happened in my workspace.

[image]

the Podfile became a ruby script not sure if it has any effect. But I changed that to default. This is my first time coding in ios so I have no idea how to fix this. this will really help me start with the project. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add missing `framework` from your `XCODE` `library`.

to do this first click on `.xproj` file and goto general , then scroll down and click on linked `framework` and `library`. and press `+ sign` to add `framwork` .

you can add `framework` only which is available in your `xcode` library.

and other `3rd party`framework which is not available in your `xcode` library you have to download from internet or update `POD` file to add `POD` related framework.

Comment: I already run the pod install and pod update on terminal buut it is stil not showing.